# How can I write html in while inside php using fetch_array data?

Tags: php, html

I tried many things but i just cant make the value of option an id from database and i cant write the option as date and title from database
im doing this so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
<select name="agenda "size="10">
            <?php
            global $connection;
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agenda where date > now() order by date", $connection);
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $i < 20)
                {
                $id = $row['id_agenda'];
                $date = $row['date'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                //here i would like to make an option with 
                //value = id_agenda and write the date_agenda and title_agenda
                //something like this
                //<option value="$row[$id]">$date $title</option>
                $i++;
                }
            ?>
            <option value="Google">meeting 2</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: what you tried with an echo and the right quote marks will work fine

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: i tried that a lot of times but the option displayed is blank

Comment: @user2476799 `print_r($result);` to check what data is pouring in

Comment: All i had to do was to place $i < 20 in front of $row = fetch, i dont know the reason why but its working that way
Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"$row[id_agenda]\">$row[date] $row[title]</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
echo "<option value=\"$id\">$date $title</option>";
```

---